# How to identify Xpath in following scanario

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7OJU.png)

I need to click on the master navigation but im not able to how to use a xpath in my code.

Comment: try this... `document.querySelector('a[href="javascript:;" > span.title ~ span')`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.